IC only works when I place my finger on it but had no issues 8 months ago. Possible causes?
CONTEXT:
I made this PCB and all worked perfectly 10 months a go. Here’s an image just to give you a better idea:

I replaced the batteries (3 AAAA batteries to be exact) and noticed that display wasn’t working unless I touched the shift register (the ones hooked to C5 and C6 respectively) with my finger.
Based on some quick research , this seems to be a noise issue (link down below)
UPDATED CONTEXT & QUESTION:
Initially this post was about me thinking it was a capacitor issue which led to noise in the IC but the capacitors are fine! However, I am once again unsure the cause of this "only works when finger on IC" issue.
ADITIONAL RESOURCES BASED ON FEEDBACK:

Here is a the main reddit post I used as part of my "research" which led me to believe it is a noise issue because he didn't have a bypass capacitor and I had thought my capacitor was broken upon initial readings (turned out I used a wrong method of reading the capacitor value)

Here is an image of the schematic of my PCB. Unchanged from one of my earlier posts:


A video link showcasing how my finger makes the timer work. Note that the power source used here is from a 5V 1Amp socket and goes via a TP4056 charge module

Another video link of me placing my finger on the J3 3 pin header instead of the shift register ICs.



You can't properly test components in-circuit.  Did you remove the caps before measuring?

@ScottSeidman No I did not remove em. I'll try that now

@ScottSeidman Just detached one of the capacitors and I got a reading 102nF. Should mean the capacitor is fine but where is all this noise coming from?
I tried different power sources too like 18650 Li-ion batteries and even another ESP32 as a power supply but the problem persists: I still have to touch the shift register for the circuit to work.
Any ideas what may be at fault?

@AmmarYasir - "where is all this noise coming from" I haven't seen any evidence that there is noise! At the moment, this looks like an XY-problem situation where your research (which isn't included in the question - please add that) has pointed you towards some kind of noise problem (that's a vague term) so that's where you're investigating. However, if touching the PCB in certain areas helps, as you said, then there are specific issues to investigate. || I see there were previous soldering problems. Also please add the current schematic.

@SamGibson Added in the resources you mentioned under the edit section of the original post and a video which make give a better context of the finger thing. As for the soldering, all worked well after I fixed some short circuits I had on my ICs and Caps.
Lemme know if you come up with a more grounded solution to this problem. Thanks!

It seems you've tested and verified that the suspected capacitor(s) are not actually at fault... please also revise the title and question accordingly.

@AmmarYasir - Thanks for adding a schematic. However it seems to be incomplete e.g. what is connected to J3? That connects to inputs on the shift registers 74HC595 U6 & U7.

@SamGibson Ah regarding J3, they're connected to output pins on my ESP32. Its a NodeMCU dev board ESP32 so thats why its not included in the schematic. They're to receive data from the code and all that. Same goes for J4 and J5. J1 is an input header where the power source from the batteries come in while J2 is an output header which powers said ESP32. Do you think it might be a problem from the ESP32 itself?

@Attie Thanks for the suggestion, made the necessary edits!

Sounds more like a bad solder joint that is causing an open, which will cause that kind of symptom with CMOS chips. The resolution of the PCB photo is quite poor so it's hard to evaluate, but I would suggest inspecting the solder joints carefully with a microscope or magnifier under good light. Sometimes probing a joint mechanically with a dental pick will help find a bad joint- if you see it move. If the board was assembled with solder paste and you see a joint or joints with a granular appearance under the microscope then the solder may not have melted sufficiently.

@SpehroPefhany Yes, I did use solder paste for the ICs. Though the circuit worked just fine some months back. Is it possible for solder joints to degrade? (especially with solder paste?) I'll make the necessary checks but I just wanna get some insight on the matter

If the joint was done well in the first place it won't degrade significantly, but it's quite possible for a bad joint to work for a while and then not.

@AmmarYasir - (a) Please do a similar "touch test" except instead of touching the area of U6 & U7, touch the pins of J3. Do you see the same behaviour? (b) Without knowing how the device is supposed to work, it's inefficient to diagnose remotely. For example, the question says: "that display wasn’t working unless I touched the shift register" but I disagree with that description. In the video, the display is clearly working before you touch those ICs. When you touch them, the numbers displayed seem to change by random amounts. IMHO the Q needs more info describing expected behaviour.

press the same area with an insulating object, such as a wooden dowel

@jsotola - The OP's video shows them doing exactly that - no effect.

@SamGibson: It's a count-down timer, and the display changes are not random. They're simply related to how long it's been since he last touched the circuit. Touch = display updates correctly, no touch = display holds current value. Since touching either shift register has the same effect, it has to be one of the two signals that the two chips have in common, RCLK and SRCLK, and it isn't a physical connection problem. Something about either the resistance or capacitance of the fingertip is allowing the circuit to work. Oscilloscope traces of those two signals would tell us a lot.

@DaveTweed - Thanks for explaining the expected operation. || I agree about the signals of interest. I don't want to write an answer that's just a hypothesis (yet), but when you look at which signals are on the J3 connector, you'll see why I asked the OP for the "J3 touch test" above. || I agree it isn't a physical connection problem at the ICs, which is why I specifically asked for the touch to be done at J3. || While scope traces of those signals might show more info, yes, I think there's also a good chance that measuring those signals would also just make the unit work normally.

@SamGibson The expected behaviour is exactly as Dave Tweed described, a countdown timer for 24:59 to 00:00. I did the test on J3 as you said (new video link for this in Additional Resources section) and it does make the timer work normally. Could there be some form of noise coming from the ESP32 output pins? I’m still just assuming its noise but you might have a better idea.
